# What are some conditions that are sufficient for the following projection property?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, convex-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X$ be a locally convex topological vector space, and let $f: X \times X \to [0,\infty]$.

Say that $f$ has the *projection property* if the following holds:

> For all compact, convex $C \subseteq X$ and all $x \in X$, there exists a unique $p_x \in C$ (the "projection" of $x$ onto $C$) such that $f(p_x, x) \leq f(y, x)$ for all $y \in C$, and, moreover, if $x \in C$, then $p_x = x$.

I am wondering:

> Are there some well-known conditions on $f$ that imply it has the projection property (e.g. $f$ is (strictly) convex and/or continuous in one/both of its arguments)? Can you point me to some references where the projection property and/or similar properties are studied?

If $f$ is continuous in its first argument, for example, then it achieves its minimum on every compact $C$. And if $f$ is also strictly convex in its first argument, then there is exactly one minimizer. But I don't see that these assumptions guarantee that the minimizer $p_x$ is $x$ whenever $x \in C$.

If possible, I would prefer not to assume that $X$ is metrizable.

Answer (score 0):

One example of such a projection is the orthogonal projection. Notice that such $f$ is a function of $\mathbf{y}$, and $\mathbf{x}$ is merely a parameter. When the underlying space $\mathbf{X}$ is Euclidean, the orthogonal projection onto a set is defined as $$P_C(\mathbf{x})=\text{argmin}_{\mathbf{y}\in C}\|\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}\|.$$
Norm is a strictly convex function, but we require the domain to be convex in order to say convexity exists. Therefore when $C$ is a convex set, this $\text{argmin}$ exists and it is unique.

For such a projection, additional properties exist. Consider $\mathbf{y}\mapsto f(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})=\text{argmin}_{\mathbf{y}\in C}\|\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}\|$, then following three claims are equivalent: \begin{align}&1)\; \mathbf{u} = P_C(\mathbf{x}) \\ 
&2)\; \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{u}\in \partial f(\mathbf{u})\\
&3)\; \langle\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{u},\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{u}\rangle\leq f(\mathbf{y}) -f(\mathbf{u}) & \forall \mathbf{y}\in \mathbf{X}
\end{align}
Another projection property is that $\mathbf{u}=P_C(\mathbf{x})$ if and only if $\langle\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{u},\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{u}\rangle\leq 0$ for all $\mathbf{y}\in C$.

Lastly, we have nonexpansivity and firm nonexpansivity. For all $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}\in \mathbf{X}$:
\begin{align}&1)\; \|P_C(\mathbf{x})-P_C(\mathbf{y})\|\leq\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\| \\ 
&2)\; \|P_C(\mathbf{x})-P_C(\mathbf{y})\|^2\leq \langle\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}, P_C(\mathbf{x})-P_C(\mathbf{y})\rangle
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, but the restriction to Euclidean spaces is too restrictive for me. I'm interested in arbitrary locally convex TVSs.